# Deep outdoor steps double as seating

Tags: deck

I bought a house that had an above ground pool built into the back deck.  The deck is a rectangle, with a quarter oval cut out of the corner so the pool could fit in there.  I removed the pool last weekend, and now have a semicircular drop from my deck to the ground, maybe 4 feet high.

I would like to put a firepit in where my pool was.  My current vision is to build deep "steps" that would basically be a bench seat following the curve of the deck around the fire pit.  Kind of like a bleacher.

Are there any code requirements for seating like this?  Is it possible?  There is already a separate stairway off the deck (which is to code as far as I know).

In Southern New Hampshire, but curious if there's anything international building code related.

https://www.dezeen.com/2013/10/20/special-feature-stairs-you-can-sit-on/

Example of what I'm talking about in above link.

Comment: @dandavis forgot to add location, thanks

Comment: that's closer, but a lot of these regulations are set by the city and or county, so you're best to contact their office if you don't want to divulge your location to the world.

Comment: My town just says that the adopted code is IBC/IRC/IMC etc. as adopted by the state of NH, which in turn says it uses the 2009 IBC/IRC/IMC etc. with no modifications. https://www.nh.gov/safety/boardsandcommissions/bldgcode/nhstatebldgcode.html

Comment: As a seat there is not so much on that but for steps there are requirements as I remember for the rise 7” and the tread 10” with the width being 30” minimum, but I haven’t don a stairway in 20 years so my numbers may be a bit off. Also over 6 or 7 risers a hand rail is required.